# VS Cloud Based Load Test is failing when sourcing data files

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I use selenium(c# with Nunit) for Testing. 
I source some xml files(which contains credential and other Inputs) for my website. While using Visual studio Cloud based Load testing, it throws File Not Fine Exception when it sources those xml file in [TestInitialize] Method

This is how i source Inside Test Initialize

InputTestData =
            new TestData(System.IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + @"\TestData"));
 PagesInformation = new Pages(System.IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + @"\PageDictionaries\SUT_Pages"));

Comment: You need to deploy the files. They need to be deployed to a location that will be available on the cloud computer. Please [edit] the question to show the file paths to the xml files and also the method of reading them in the `TestInitialize` method.

Comment: What is `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`? What does it expand to on your local machine and what does it expand to on the cloud computer? What have you done to make the files in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` available on the cloud computer?

Comment: sorry, Code Edited .

Comment: I added DeploymentItem in my Test Class for my Directories as well as in the Test Setting File                 `[DeploymentItem("C:\\TFS\\Product\\Source\\Dev\\Projects\\Tests\\Regression\\Eus.CTM.RegressionTests\\Core\\TestData")]
    [DeploymentItem("C:\\TFS\\Product\\Source\\Dev\\Projects\\Tests\\Regression\\Eus.CTM.RegressionTests\\Core\\PageDictionaries")]`

Answer (score 1):

Load tests run by Visual Studio Team Services, i.e. in the Microsoft Azure cloud, run on computers that we have very little control over. They are run under Microsoft's user accounts with the permissions of those users. All of the test suite and related files must be contained within the package that is transferred from the test development computer to the cloud. That normally means that everything must be part of the Visual Studio solution. Files containing test data must have their `Copy to output directory` set to one of the `Copy ...` values. The files would then be found in one of the directories named by the context parameters with `$...Directory...` or `$...Dir...` in their names. One of the directory names can also be seen in the `Connection string` property of the data source  where it is shown as `|DataDirectory|\filename.csv`.

The question and comments show that the data file is expected to be in a subdirectory of `C:\TFS\Product\Source\`. The cloud test runs I have done appear to deploy all the test files into a directory such as `d:\0\td\c3fd4\TestRun`. I would expect the permissions to be set so that directories other than the `d:\...\TestRun` cannot be written by the test suite; to prevent malicious test suites from vandalising the computers.

The solution to the question is to deploy the test data files into directories that will be copied to the computer running the test.